# Revert buffer messages in echo area obscure minibuffer

Tags: magit, minibuffer, echo-area

My issue is that when I switch git branches in a project, each file that changes needs its buffer to revert, and this message is spat to the echo area for each file. If I try to run a command from the minibuffer, anything displayed in the minibuffer (the command I am typing as well as the completion suggestions) are temporarily overwritten by the revert buffer message.

Is there a way to suppress these messages so that I am able to run commands using smex in the minibuffer?

Comment: If you provide us with the exact message, we can grep the source code and find the function responsible.  Otherwise, we start tracing `revert-buffer` and see lots of messages about yes/no and variables and command arguments to suppress confirmation, etc ....   In other words, unless someone knows exactly what message you are seeing, the question becomes somewhat of a guessing game and/or is more time consuming to locate an answer.  A grep search for the exact message would *probably* make answering the question a breeze ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have `global-auto-revert-mode` on?
Those revert messages can be a bit "spamy" and you can turn
them of with `(setq auto-revert-verbose nil)`.